# Constructing a quadrilateral using the method of translation - Kiselev

Tags: euclidean-geometry, geometric-construction

Ending the fourteenth chapter of Planimetry is the following construction:

[image]

Why is this a construction, when the quadrilateral in question is already given.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The quadrilateral is not given. Given are only the lengths of its sides and the length of $EF$.

Now you have to reassemble this quadrilateral. You can imagine as some sticks which are appart of each other and you have to get them together.

Comment: Ah, yes. Thank you. The part that threw me was at AE = EB without proof. I didn't get it until I physically moved two things together.